# How do I fix this While statement in my Pythagorean theorem code?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, statements

So I am trying to write a simple code that will do the Pythagorean theorem for me after I input A, B and C but the code is skipping my While statements, and I have tried rewriting them as if statements to see if that works and again it will skip it, I need some help Please and Thank you Btw I do realize that in the picture that my while loops are open and have nothing ending them but I did have that in there at one point but I had taken them out when I changed to If statements.[My Code I cant seem to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpJBk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're taking `input()` from the user, it is returned as a string. Suppose user enters `1` it will be stored as `"1" # which is a string`. Now when you compared `Yes_No == 1` it returned `False` because `"1" == 1` is `False`.

---

So you need to parse (convert) it into a number (integer), which can be done by passing string to `int()` function. It will return the integer representation of that string. Do the same with all the inputs and your problem will be solved!

---

Another problem with your code is that you're not updating the value of `Yes_No` in any of the `while` loop. Which means that it will result in infinite loop, it will keep executing the while loop because once the condition becomes `True` it will not become `False` because value of `Yes_No` is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `input()` the input comes as a string, and in your `while` loop you set your condition to be equal to 1 (as an integer).

A solution to this would be:

```
varname = int(input("")) #this way it converts your input into an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

As the python documentation points out, the input function returns a string:

> input([prompt])
>   If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output 
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

If you didn't know that and you wanted to debug and figure out, you can do something like `print(type(Yes_No))` and you can see that it is a string type, so when you evaluate this expression: `while Yes_No == 1`, it returns false.

So the fix in this situation is to change your input line to

```
 Yes_No = int(input("Do you have the hypotenuse? For yes press 1 or for no press 2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that explains a lot, and will probably help with future questions so thank you once again